# skipping dpkg-genchange step (Debian)

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm building binary only package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
```

The build actually runs successfully, but I have deleted previous version of the package and now dpkg-genchanges complains:

```
   dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package `zzz' in `../zzz_01-4_amd64.deb'.
 dpkg-genchanges -b >../zzz_01-4_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: binary-only upload - not including any source code
dpkg-genchanges: error: cannot fstat file ../zzz_01-1_amd64.deb: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genchanges gave error exit status 2
```

Is there any way to skip this step? I really do not need it, as I'm building deb package for local use and previous versions are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What lines did you see in `debian/files` after `dpkg-buildpackage`?  It should be something like:

```
hello_2.8-2_i386.deb devel optional
```

This file is created and updated by `dpkg-deb` and `dpkg-genchanges` read it to get files to be listed in the `.changes` file.

`dpkg-deb` just appends a new line to `debian/files` if it already exists, so it's essential to make sure it gets removed in the beginning of binary build in `debian/rules`.  `dh_clean` would be help for that.